# How can I have an overlay appear on all of my web pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm setting up a website and I would like the ability for a user to press a button to open an overlay (code is below), which would appear on every web page.

I have already tried going through each individual file, pasting the code but it is becoming tedious, due to the number of files that i have and a number of file conflicts.

```
<style>
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
  <div id="text">Overlay Text</div>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <button onclick="on()">Hide</button>
</div>

<script>
function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you are using a server side language like PHP you can use an include() to add a chunk of code to each page. Otherwise your options are pretty limited, because even a JavaScript solution would necessitate editing every page.

Comment: You can start by placing your code in a separate.js file, so every html file can load that same file. Then, you can use `createElement` to place the overlay div in the DOM. If you have errors, you need to paste those here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unless you have the ability to use includes or fragments, you either have to include a div on every page OR you could use jquery html to insert via a global js file.

something like this inside your click event:

```js
$( ".btn" ).on( "click", function() {
    $('#overlay').html("<div id="overlay"><div id="text">Overlay Text</div></div>");
});
```

Comment: I cant seem to get your suggestion to work, I have a js file with the overlay script, but what do I do with the css? At the moment, I have a file with both the script and css, and just the scrip, niether of which work.